# Mysql table or query optimisation

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I am running the following query and however I change it, it still takes almost 5 seconds to run which is completely unacceptable...

The query:

```
SELECT cat1, cat2, cat3, PRid, title, genre, artist, author, actors, imageURL, 
lowprice, highprice, prodcatID, description
from products
where title like '%' AND imageURL <> '' AND cat1 = 'Clothing and accessories'
order by userrating desc
limit 500
```

I've tried taking out the "like %", taking out the "imageURl <> ''" but still the same. I've tried returning only 1 colum, still the same.

I have indexes on almost every column in the table, certainly all the columns mentioned in the query.

This is basically for a category listing. If I do a fulltext search for something in the title column which has a fulltext index, it takes less than a second.

Should I add another fulltext index to column cat1 and change the query focus to "match against" on that column?

Am I expecting too much?

The table has just short of 3 million rows.

Comment: can you show us the table schema

Comment: 3 mil row table and index on almost every column.. that's just not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you had an index on every column. Do you have an index such as?

```
alter table products add index (cat1, userrating)
```

If you don't, give it a try. Run that query and let me know if it run faster.

Also, I assume you're actually setting some kind of filter instead of the `%` on the title, field, right?

Comment: Its still not brilliant but cut time more than in half - thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

You should rather have the cat1 as a integer, then a string in these 3 million rows. You must also index correctly. If indexing all columns only improved, then it'd be a default thing the system would do.

Apart from that, `title LIKE '%'` doesn't do anything. I guess you use it to search so it becomes `` `title LIKE 'search%' ``

Do you use any sort of framework to fetch this? Getting 500 rows with a lot of columns can exhaust the system if your framework saves this to a large array. It may probably not be the case, but:
Try running a ordinary `$query = mysql_query()` and `while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query))`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to add an index with the columns queried: title, imageURL and cat1.
Second improvement: use the SQL server cache, it will deadly improve the speed.
Last improvement: if you query is always like that, only the values change, then use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am quite sure that a `%` as the first char in a `LIKE` clause, gives you a full table scan for that column (in your case you won't have that full table scan executed because you already have restricting clauses in the `AND` clause). 
Beside that try to add an index on `cat1` column. Also, try to add other criterias to your query, in order to reduce the size of the dataset - your working data set (the number of rows that matches your query, without the `LIMIT` clause) might be too big also.